# Access variable in Jinja file from python module

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja file, result.j2 which contain a variable defined as below :

```
{% set file_name = 'foo' %}
```

I am trying to find a way to access this variable from python module. So, lets say I have
access.py module and I would like to import the value 'foo' in access.py so I can use it.

I tried with below :

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader("./"), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)

template = env.get_template("./result.j2")

print(template)
```

however, this is not working. I think the issue that the variable is under set command and no render for this file

Comment: Any variable set with the `set` jinja command is scoped only to that block of the template.  If you want to pass a value back your Python app code, the best option in my opinion is to put it into a form and POST it back ti the app code when submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Any example please would be helpful

Comment: Well, I think the first thing that I would need clarified to give you an example is why you're setting a filename in the template this way in the first place, as this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why not set the filename in the code that is rendering the template or which a user action in the template will go to?  What is the expected user workflow? or is the filename somehow based on user action but not directly input by them?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. So, this was an example. it is a variable name created earlier and I would like to access it from python module. So let say in jinja file .j2 we have defined a variable called {% set x = 100 %} .. I would like to expose this 100 into a python code